# Ending of "The Man From Earth: Holocene"

Tags: ending, the-man-from-earth-holocene

I didn't understand ending of ***The Man From Earth: Holocene***. Just after cave painting, we see a man from FBI talks about guy who is found dead, who looks like John(s), but with description of black hair. But John hair was turning grey. And Moreover, where's the Pihip. And what we can conclude from ending of this movie.

Comment: Please do not combine multiple questions into one post.

Comment: I'm just asking what happens at ending of the movie, which I didn't understand. And that I aksed in 3 different ways, I hope all 3 question says one thing: what is happening. Fact is: I didn't understand that conversation from FBI. Nothing. So, if you know the answer can you please.

Answer (score -1):

Just seen the movie second time. My guess is, that as everything on the world is balanced, if there was a good guy, John, than there was also a similar bad guy, the "Antichrist". They had to die the same time.